# Create a 300 DPI Din A6 pdf in Prawn

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

I am trying to generate a PDF with Prawn that has 300 DPI. The pdf will be printed on a DIN A6 page and needs to look good with 300 DPI.

How can this be done?

Comment: Unless you are including bitmaps, PDFs have no maximum resolution - fonts and vector elements will scale to any DPI you like. Can you edit your question with the code/research you have presently?